# How can I get bash/zsh to change some text from "foo.foo.foo" to "foo foo foo" with a script/alias?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I can maybe use `<` or `>` or `|`. Maybe I need to use grep?

Comment: What do you mean by a text? a file or some text in a file? `echo "foo.foo.foo" | sed 's/\./ /g'`

Comment: @K.D.G i) you need to create a separate account for each SE site, but if you use the same credentials, the accounts will be linked. ii) While this site is indeed limited to Ubuntu exclusively, I don't see anything here that would be irrefutable proof that you are not using Ubuntu, so I also se no reason to close it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can make a function and add to the end of your `~/.bashrc`, for example:

```
nodot() {  echo "$1" | sed 's/\./ /g' ; }
```

usage example:

```
$ nodot foo.foo.foo
foo foo foo
```

You can use this function in zsh too, just add to your `~/.zshrc` instead.

Comment: @tbodt changing an accepted answer to completely replace it with another current answer is simply not done.

Answer (score 28):

You can use **tr** command to convert character.

```
% echo "foo.foo.foo" | tr '.' ' ' 
foo foo foo
```

Comment: cool tips never hear of "tr" before

Comment: @K.D.G Thanks :) Btw, I would highly suggest to you to read few books. You can start from the following one: https://www.amazon.com/Linux-Command-Line-Complete-Introduction/dp/1593273894

Comment: `tr` is actually meant for exactly this purpose. `sed` is overkill.

Comment: +1 precisely for `tr`, which is a very useful tool that a lot of people don't seem to know about for some reason. Way simpler than `sed` for converting entire classes of characters.

Comment: Never write it in 'C' if you can do it in 'awk'; 
Never do it in 'awk' if 'sed' can handle it; 
Never use 'sed' when 'tr' can do the job; 
Never invoke 'tr' when 'cat' is sufficient; 
Avoid using 'cat' whenever possible. --Taylor's Laws of Programming

Comment: Nice answer. This answer should be accepted.

Answer (score 24):

Using pure bash:

```
bash-3.2$ a='a.a.a'
bash-3.2$ echo "${a/./ }"
a a.a
bash-3.2$ echo "${a//./ }"
a a a
```

Answer (score 9):

Using `Internal Field Separator (IFS)` variable:

```
bash-4.3$ old_ifs=$IFS
bash-4.3$ IFS="."
bash-4.3$ var="foo.foo.foo"
bash-4.3$ echo $var
foo foo foo
bash-4.3$ IFS=$old_ifs
```

This can be put nicely into a function:

```
split_dot()
{

    string="$1"

    if set | grep -q "IFS";
    then
       ifs_unset="false"
       old_ifs=$IFS
    else
       ifs_unset="true"
    fi

    IFS="."
    echo $string
    if [ "$ifs_unset" == "true" ];
    then
       unset IFS
    else
       IFS=$old_ifs
    fi
}
```

And run as so:

```
bash-4.3$ split_dot "foo.baz.bar"                                                                             
foo baz bar
```

Comment: Resetting `IFS` is a more tricky than just saving it to a variable and restoring the value. An unset `IFS` and an empty `IFS` have different behaviour, so you need to check whether it is unset or just empty, in  case it was empty before.

Comment: @muru since functions run in subshell, i don't see how it can be unset unless you explicitly do so. please explain

Comment: Functions don't run in subshells. Only some variables have different scope (the positional parameters, and a few others in listed in https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Functions.html). That's why we have the `local` keyword.

Comment: So if OP had unset `IFS` for some reason previously, this function would set it to empty, which does have different behaviour.

Comment: Agreed with @muru . Instead, just set `IFS` for the command: `IFS=... echo ...`.

Comment: @fedorqui unfortunately even that won't work; since the IFS value is set too late for the current statement being parsed. You'd actually have to use a subshell `(IFS=.; echo ...)`. Since this answer used a function, Serg could just change the braces to parentheses and not worry about resetting IFS at all

Comment: @fedorqui it cannot be set for command, tried that already `IFS="." echo $var`

Comment: @muru  so, in case it was unset, does it have any effect on what is being done here, i.e. setting IFS="." and then echoing the string ?  I mean, i don't quite understand how does it affect the end result

Comment: @muru good point! In fact I just remembered a question I asked myself in SO: [Setting IFS for a single statement](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33416877/1983854), it is a pity I don't have a proper bash here with me now to do some tests :)

Comment: @fedorqui you might find my similar question on U&L interesting: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/264635/70524 (Gilles always gives very good answers)

Comment: OK, I've updated my answer to check for unset IFS. Let me know what you think guys

Answer (score 4):

Anyone missed `awk`/`perl`/`python`/`go`:

---

```
% awk '{gsub(/[.]/, " ", $0); print}' <<<'foo.foo.foo'                      
foo foo foo
```

---

```
% perl -pe 's/\./ /g' <<<'foo.foo.foo'                                      
foo foo foo
```

---

```
% python -c 'import sys; print sys.stdin.read().replace(".", " ")' <<<'foo.foo.foo'
foo foo foo
```

---

```
% cat input.go
package main

import (
    "os"
    "strings"
    "fmt"
)

func main () {
    args := os.Args
    if len(args) != 2 {
        fmt.Println("Not enough arguments")
        return
    }
    out := strings.Replace(args[1], ".", " ", -1)
    fmt.Println(out)
}

% go run input.go 'foo.foo.foo' 
foo foo foo
```

Answer (score 1):

One can use `xargs` also. Here is a one-liner using `xargs`

```
$ echo "foo.foo.foo" | xargs -d .
foo foo foo
```