# How to separate command output to individual lines

Tags: bash, scripts

```
list=`ls -a R*`
echo $list
```

Inside a shell script, this echo command will list all the files from current directory starting with R, but in one line. How can I print each item on one line?

I need a generic command for all the scenarios happening with `ls`, `du`, `find -type -d`, etc.

Comment: General note: *do not do this with ls, it will break on any weird filenames*. See [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If the output of the command contains multiple lines, then quote your variables to preserve those newlines when echoing:

```
echo "$list"
```

Otherwise, the shell will expand and split the variable contents on whitespace (spaces, newlines, tabs) and those will be lost.

Answer (score 17):

Instead of ill-advisedly putting `ls` output in a variable and then `echo`ing it, which removes all the colors, use

```
ls -a1
```

From `man ls`

```
       -1     list one file per line.  Avoid '\n' with -q or -b
```

I don't advise you do anything with the output of `ls`, except display it :)

Use, for example, shell globs and a `for` loop to do something with files...

```
shopt -s dotglob                  # to include hidden files*

for i in R/*; do echo "$i"; done
```

* this won't include the current directory `.` or its parent `..` though

Comment: I'd recommend to replace: `echo "$i"` with  `printf "%s\n" "$i"`  (that one won't choke if a filename starts with a "-"). Actually, most of the time `echo something` should be replaced with `printf "%s\n" "something"` .

Comment: @OlivierDulac They all start with `R` here, but in general, yes. Yet even for scripting, attempting *always* to accommodate leading `-` in paths causes trouble: people assume `--`, which only some commands support, signifies end of options. I've seen `find . [tests] -exec [cmd] -- {} \;` where `[cmd]` doesn't support `--`. Every path there starts with `.` anyway! *But that's no argument against replacing `echo` with `printf '%s\n'`.* Here, one can replace the whole loop with  `printf '%s\n' R/*`. Bash has `printf` as a builtin, so there's effectively no limit to the number/length of arguments.

Answer (score 13):

While putting it in quotes as @muru [suggested](https://askubuntu.com/a/972082/85695) will indeed do what you asked for, you might also want to consider using an array for this. For example:

```
IFS=$'\n' dirs=( $(find . -type d) )
```

The `IFS=$'\n'` tells bash to only split the output on newline characcters o get each element of the array. Without it, it will split on spaces, so `a file name with spaces.txt` would be 5 separate elements instead of one. 
This approach will break if your file/directory names can contain newlines (`\n`) though. It will save each *line* of the command's output as an element of the array.

<sub>Note that I also changed the old-style `` `command` `` to `$(command)` which is the preferred syntax.</sub>

You now have an array called `$dirs`, each bof whose elements is a line of the output of the previous command. For example:

```
$ find . -type d
.
./olad
./ho
./ha
./ads
./bar
./ga
./da
$ IFS=$'\n' dirs=( $(find . -type d) )
$ for d in "${dirs[@]}"; do
    echo "DIR: $d"
  done
DIR: .
DIR: ./olad
DIR: ./ho
DIR: ./ha
DIR: ./ads
DIR: ./bar
DIR: ./ga
DIR: ./da
```

Now, because of some bash strangeness (see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/264642/22222)), you will need to reset `IFS` back to the original value after doing this. So, either save it and reasign:

```
oldIFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n' dirs=( $(find . -type d) ) 
IFS="$oldIFS"
```

Or do it manually:

```
IFS=" "$'\t\n '
```

Alternatively, just close the current terminal. Your new one will have the original IFS set again.

Comment: I might have suggested something like this, but then the part about `du` makes it look OP is more interested in preserving the output format.

Comment: How can I make this work if the directory names contain spaces?

Comment: @dessert whoops! It should work with spaces (but not newlines) now. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Note that you should reset or unset IFS after that array assignment. https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/264635/70524

Comment: @muru oh wow, thanks, I'd forgotten about that weirdness.

Answer (score 5):

#### If you *must* store the output and you want an array, `mapfile` makes it easy.

First, consider if you *need* to store your command's output at all. If you don't, just run the command.

If you decide you want to read the output of a command as an array of lines, it's true that one way to do it is to disable globbing, set `IFS` to split on lines, use command substitution inside the `(` `)` array creation syntax, and reset `IFS` afterwards, which [is more complex](https://askubuntu.com/questions/851113/how-can-i-get-bash-zsh-to-change-some-text-from-foo-foo-foo-to-foo-foo-foo-w/851191#comment1308125_851191) than it seems. [terdon's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/972090/22949) covers some of that approach. **But I suggest you use `mapfile`, the Bash shell's [built-in](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Builtins) command for reading text as an array of lines, instead.** Here's a simple case where you're reading from a file:

```bash
mapfile < filename
```

This reads lines into an array called `MAPFILE`. Without the [input redirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirecting-Input) `< filename`, you would be reading from the shell's [standard input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_.28stdin.29) (typically your terminal) instead of the file named by *`filename`*. To read into an array other than the default `MAPFILE`, pass its name. For example, this reads into the array `lines`:

```bash
mapfile lines < filename
```

Another default behavior you might choose to change is that the [newline characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) at the ends of lines are left in place; they appear as the last character in each array element (unless the input ended without a newline character, in which case the last element doesn't have one). To chomp these newlines so they don't appear in the array, pass the `-t` option to `mapfile`. For example,  this reads to the array `records` and does not write trailing newline characters to its array elements:

```bash
mapfile -t records < filename
```

You can also use `-t` without passing an array name; that is, it works with an implicit array name of `MAPFILE`, too.

The `mapfile` shell builtin supports other options, and it can alternatively be invoked as `readarray`. Run `help mapfile` (and `help readarray`) for details.

**But you don't want to read from a file, you want to read from the output of a command.** To achieve that, use [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution). This command reads lines from the command *`some-command`* with *`arguments...`* as its command-line arguments and places in them in `mapfile`'s default array `MAPFILE`, with their terminating newline characters removed:

```bash
mapfile -t < <(some-command arguments...)
```

Process substitution replaces `<(some-command arguments...)` with an actual filename from which the output of running `some-command arguments...` can be read. The file is a [named pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe) rather than a [regular file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_file_types#Regular_file) and, on Ubuntu, it will be named like `/dev/fd/63` (sometimes with some other number than `63`), but you don't need to concern yourself with the details, because the shell takes care of it all behind the scenes.

<sup>You might think you could forgo process substitution by using `some-command arguments... | mapfile -t` instead, but that won't work because, when you have a [pipeline](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pipelines) of multiple commands separated by `|`, Bash runs runs all commands in [subshells](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/SubShell). Thus both `some-command arguments...` and `mapfile -t` run in their own [environments](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Execution-Environment), initialized from but separate from the environment of the shell in which you run the pipeline. In the subshell where `mapfile -t` runs, the `MAPFILE` array *does* get populated, but then that array is discarded when the command ends. `MAPFILE` is never created or modified for the caller.</sup>

**Here's what the example** in [terdon's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/972090/22949) looks like, in entirety, if you use `mapfile`:

```bash
mapfile -t dirs < <(find . -type d)
```

```bash
for d in "${dirs[@]}"; do
    echo "DIR: $d"
done
```

That's it. You don't need to [check if `IFS` was set](https://askubuntu.com/questions/851113/how-can-i-get-bash-zsh-to-change-some-text-from-foo-foo-foo-to-foo-foo-foo-w/851191#comment1308125_851191), keep track of whether not it was set and with what value, set it to a newline, then reset or re-unset it later. You don't have to disable [globbing](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion) (for example, with `set -f`)--which is really needed if you are to use that method seriously, since filenames may contain `*`, `?`, and `[`--then re-enable it (`set +f`) afterwards.

You can also replace that particular loop entirely with a single `printf` command--though this is not actually a benefit of `mapfile`, as you can do that whether you use `mapfile` or another method to populate the array. Here's a shorter version:

```bash
mapfile -t < <(find . -type d)
printf 'DIR: %s\n' "${MAPFILE[@]}"
```

It's important to keep in mind that, as [terdon mentions](https://askubuntu.com/a/972090/22949), operating line-by-line is not always appropriate, and will not work correctly with filenames that contain newlines. I recommend against naming files that way, but it *can* happen, including by accident.

#### There isn't really a one-size-fits-all solution.

You asked for "a generic command for all the scenarios," and the approach of using `mapfile` somewhat approaches that goal, but I urge you to reconsider your requirements.

The task shown above is better achieved with just a single `find` command:

```bash
find . -type d -printf 'DIR: %p\n'
```

You could also use an external command like `sed` to add `DIR:`  to the beginning of each line. This is arguably somewhat ugly, and unlike that find command it will add extra "prefixes" within filenames that contain newlines, but it does work regardless of its input so it sort of meets your requirements *and it is still preferable to reading the output into a variable or array*:

```bash
find . -type d | sed 's/^/DIR: /'
```

If you need to list and also perform an action on each directory found, such as running *`some-command`* and passing the directory's path as an argument, `find` lets you do that too:

```
find . -type d -print -exec some-command {} \;
```

As another example, let's return to the general task of adding a prefix to each line. Suppose I want to see the output of `help mapfile` but number the lines. I would not actually use `mapfile` for this, nor any other method that reads it into a shell variable or shell array. Supposing `help mapfile | cat -n` doesn't give the formatting I want, I can use `awk`:

```bash
help mapfile | awk '{ printf "%3d: %s\n", NR, $0 }'
```

**Reading all the output of a command in to a single variable or array is sometimes useful and appropriate, but it has major disadvantages.** Not only do you have to deal with the additional complexity of using your shell when an existing command or combination of existing commands may already do what you need as well or better, but the entire output of the command has to be stored in memory. Sometimes you may know that isn't a problem, but sometimes you may be processing a large file.

An alternative that is commonly attempted--and sometimes done right--is to read input line-by-line with `read -r` in a loop. If you don't need to store previous lines while operating on later lines, and you have to use long input, then it may be better than `mapfile`. But it, too, [should be avoided in cases when you can just pipe it to a command that can do the work, which is most cases](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice?noredirect=1&lq=1).